# Boot disc Dual-Core CPU stress tool?

Tags: bootable-media, prime95

Looking for a tool that can test a dual-core cpu via a boot disc, thus bypassing Windows (and ensuring that only the hardware is being tested).

UBCD4Win's included Prime95 is an older version and it can't run two threads at once. Ditto for UBCD.

Any idea? And while I'm asking, is there a boot tool for GPU's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you are looking for, but as an alternative how about rolling your own Windows boot disc using [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) and making sure you include the [multhreaded version of Prime95.](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=6572)

Comment: @user26353: Sounds like a plan! Can you give me some pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two linux live-cd's you can use to stress test your computer.

- [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=pts_desktop_live)
- [stresslinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)

Comment: @Nifle: Do any/both test dual-core processors?

Comment: @Ssvarc - I don't know explicitly, but I can't see why not.